# my trigger wont print what i want it to

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging

so im a student working in Oracle SQL and i wrote a trigger to notify me if the item quantity is under a certain value. my trigger was created without compilation errors but when i test it i do not see the output that i want... I am sure there may be better ways to do certain parts of this but i am concerned mostly with how to get it to print to the command line. also if possible i would like the first if statement to contain a break statement so that the quantity cannot be less than 0. is that done by addint 'BREAK;' before the 'END IF;'?

```
SQL> @345lowqtytrigger
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER low_qty_trigger
  2  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF vnd_itm_qty ON Vending_Machine_Item
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5  tempstr varchar2(1000);
  6  name varchar2(1000);
  7  vndadd varchar2(1000);
  8  tempint int;
 9  cursor itm_des_cursor is
 10  SELECT itm_des FROM item WHERE itm_id = item.itm_id;
 11  cursor vnd_addr_cursor is
 12  SELECT vnd_addr FROM Vending_Machine WHERE vnd_id = Vending_Machine.vnd_id;
 13  BEGIN
 14          open itm_des_cursor;
 15          fetch itm_des_cursor into name;
 16          open vnd_addr_cursor;
 17          fetch vnd_addr_cursor into vndadd;
 18          IF :NEW.vnd_itm_qty < 0 THEN
 19          tempstr := concat(:new.vnd_id,concat(' can not have less than 0 quantity for ',name));
 20          dbms_output.put_line(tempstr);
 21  end if;
 22  tempint := :new.vnd_itm_qty_max*.15;
 23          IF
 24          :NEW.vnd_itm_qty <= tempint
 25          and
 26          :NEW.vnd_itm_qty >= 0
 27          THEN
 28          tempstr := concat('There will be less than ',
 29  concat(to_char(tempint),
 30  concat(' of ',
 31  concat(name,
 32  concat(' in Vending Machine ',
 33  concat(to_char(:new.vnd_id),
 34  concat(' located at ',vndadd)))))));
 35  dbms_output.put_line(tempstr);
 36  END IF;
 37  close itm_des_cursor;
 38  close vnd_addr_cursor;
 39  END;
 40  /

Trigger created.

SQL> SET ECHO OFF;
No errors.
SQL> spool off;

TEST CASE

SQL> update vending_machine_item set vnd_itm_qty = 1 where vnd_id = 956 and itm_id = 193;


1 row updated.
```

Comment: Put your logging statements into a table. Then query your table to see the results. But this could mean looking into atomic transactions if you rollback but still want to keep logs.

Comment: what do you mean by my logging statements?

Comment: Instead of using `dbms_output.put_line(tempstr);` create some table for your message, say, `VENDING_MSG`, and have your trigger insert into that table: `INSERT INTO vending_msg(msg) VALUES(tempstr);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you testing this?  It has to be in an interactive session to see any output generated by dbms_output.  Try an update on vending_machine_item from a sql*plus session with [set serveroutput on.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699298)

Comment: i put 'set serveroutput on;' just after my begin statement and got this error 11/2     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
11/6     PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
I also tried using 'dbms_output.enable();' it compiled fine however still didnt print.

Comment: Set serveroutput on is a SQL*Plus command. Enter it before you issue your update.  It is not a valid PL/SQL statement.

Comment: thanks i took it out of my script and just put it on the command line then tried my update statement and it printed the both of the strings instead of just one of them.